# Nexus 7 (2012 Wifi) Custom kernel bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, kernel

I trying to build custom kernel for my Nexus 7 (2012 Wifi) device.
Changed few things builded successfull, no bootloop. But I enable this in menuconfig:
Device Drivers -> Network device support -> Wireless LAN -> Ralink driver support.
After flashing got bootloop.
How can i get some log about a problem?

Comment: Some devices can output the kernel boot log using a special adapter that uses the 3.5mm audio port. Not sure about your Nexus 7.

Comment: I was referring such a cable: [serial console which can be accessed through the headset socket](http://www.pabr.org/consolejack/consolejack.en.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build with module it was a working path.